# Robust textarea html?

Tags: javascript, html

Does there exist some sort of javascript framework with which I can easily have a code editor type textarea in html? Basically I want to be able to read input from it, highlight/change text color of certain words, and have line numbers. In terms of look I'd like something similar to jdoodle (see below) but with the ability to customize which words get highlighted.

[image: jdoodle]

Thanks

Comment: Several depending on exactly what you want to do. Unfortunately "What Library Can I use to Do X" is off-topic for stack overflow, as it's often primarily opinion based. https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/ is probably the most powerful that comes to mind, but you likely want something more light weight.

Comment: https://codemirror.net/

Answer (score 0):

This is an opinion based question, but based on my experience these are 10 Best jQuery and HTML5 WYSIWYG Plugins (html textarea, with text highlight ability, etc.)

1. Froala.
2. ContentTools
3. Raptor Editor. Raptor
4. Aloha
5. TinyMCE
6. bootstrap3-wysiwyg
7. Summernote
8. CKEditor